# SSRS IIF Multiple expression not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Please see pic [image]

For some reason my expression is not working and I cannot figure out why...

What I'm trying to do is check the UseByDate if it's blank set time to blank AND if pickeddatetime is blank (time field) also set to blank if not blank use pickeddatetime.  However my expression doesn't seem to be working correctly for some reason?

```
=IIF(Fields!UseByDate.Value is nothing, nothing, IIF(Fields!PickedDateTime is nothing, nothing, FORMAT(System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Fields!PickedDateTime.Value), "HH:mm")))
```

I've checked the pickeddatetime value and it is definitely null for this row.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the time format option on the cell by its properties ? There is work around for this, is that you can set visibility of the cell depending on the your values.

Comment: I checked the format properties and HH:mm was set however I removed this and it hasn't fixed it... I don't want the whole column to be invisible, just the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Fields!PickedDateTime` with `Fields!PickedDateTime.Value`

Answer (score 1):

I think the way the expression is written isn't checking for nothing correctly. Try:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!UseByDate.Value)=True, nothing, IIF(IsNothing(Fields!PickedDateTime)=True, nothing, FORMAT(System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Fields!PickedDateTime.Value), "HH:mm")))
```